# Model doesn't predict in eval mode using the same dataset

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have created simple model to detect moving object and display its coordinates. Dataset was consisting of thermal videos captured from above, where the target was almost a dot. My model was predicting coordinates with accuracy of 1 pixel in 80% of all training frames.

However, when I switched model to the `eval()` mode, just for a try, I gave the same inputs as for training and the results were way different. How is it possible and what can I do to restore previous accuracy??

Here's my model:

```
  (conv1): Conv2d(1, 40, kernel_size=(6, 6), stride=(5, 5))
  (conv2): Conv2d(40, 40, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1))
  (conv3): Conv2d(40, 120, kernel_size=(3, 4), stride=(3, 3))
  (relu0): ReLU()
  (maxpool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (flatten1): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
  (lstm): LSTM(20, 175, num_layers=2)
  (flatten2): Flatten(start_dim=0, end_dim=-1)
  (linear3): Linear(in_features=21000, out_features=2, bias=True)
```

And optimizer:

```
Adam (
Parameter Group 0
    amsgrad: False
    betas: (0.9, 0.999)
    capturable: False
    differentiable: False
    eps: 1e-08
    foreach: None
    fused: False
    lr: 0.0005
    maximize: False
    weight_decay: 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A common source for such behavior is when Dropout or BatchNorm is applied (since it leads to different network behavior during training and evaluation), this is however not the case in your model as far as I can tell. Instead of using model.eval() you can also try model.train(mode=False) to see if the behavior is consistent. Obtaining a single batch with 80% accuracy while the average remains below this can however happen. Thus ensure that the two data sources you are testing on are identical and that the model is not reinitialized or otherwise altered between training and testing.